# неверное вычисление height()

Tags: jquery, height

добрый день, делаю листалку, мне надо получить высоту следующего вложения что бы отресайзить родительский блок листалки, так выглядит структура (блоков i_n_block много, все абсолюты, отображаются по z-index)

```
<div class="wapper_important_news clearfix">

<div class="i_n_static fs36 regular">ВАЖНО!</div> 

<div data-rel="n" class="i_n_block clearfix">

            <div class="left">
                <div class="i_n_date fs13 light">DATE</div>
            </div>

            <div class="right">
                <div class="table-cell">

                    <a href="#href" class="underline">
                    <div class="i_n_title fs16 bold">TEXT_HREF</div>
                    </a>
                    <div class="i_n_desc fs16 light">TEXT</div>

                </div>
             </div>

</div>
        <div class="i-n-control">
            <div class="left"></div>
            <div class="right"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

а вот так выглядит js который пытается ресайзить:

```
var a = $(".i_n_block:visible");
$(".wapper_important_news").height(a.next().find(".right").height());
```

но при выполнении height() выдаёт 100px, на каждом блоке(там такой высоты вообще нигде нет). если брать размер текущего блока(без next/prev), то все работает нормально, но мне надо во время анимации менять высоту. как лучше решить эту проблему и почему, собственно, не получается получить высоту соседних элементов?

Comment: не понял, относительно кокого блока вы хотите выровнить? a.next() в вашем случае это i-n-control..

Comment: относительно .right, в нем текст который влияет на высоту. в моем случае это все таки следующий нужный блок, ибо a.next().hasClass("i_n_block") вернул мне true. уточнение из вопроса: "блоков i_n_block много", это для примера он тут один

Comment: ?? https://jsfiddle.net/x7Lbdjxw/

Comment: предупреждать надо...))

Comment: последнее предложение из моего последнего комментария объясняет это поведение

Comment: может быть это из за того что height() работает только с видимыми элементами? всплыло в памяти что то такое

Comment: да нет, работает вроде... https://jsfiddle.net/x7Lbdjxw/1/

Comment: точно, он работает с visibility:hidden, а вот с display:none уже не работает. теперь другой вопрос, можно ли заставить jq использовать свойство visibility вместо display в анимациях?)

Comment: проблема в другом, при visibility:hidden, блок продолжает занемать место, display:none нет....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Единственный вариант, имхо, вначале давать блоку `display` а потом счетать высоту...

```js
$("#res").text($(".wapper_important_news").height());

$("button").click(function() {
  var a = $(".i_n_block:visible");
  a.css('display', 'none');
  a.next().css('display', 'block');

  $(".wapper_important_news").height(a.next().find(".right").height());
  $("#res").text(a.next().find(".right").height())
})
```

```css
.right {
  width: 50px;
  word-wrap: break-word
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<b>ресультат height: </b><span id="res"></span>
<button>Click me</button>

<div class="wapper_important_news clearfix" style="border: 5px solid red">
  <div class="i_n_static fs36 regular">ВАЖНО!</div>
  <div data-rel="n" class="i_n_block clearfix">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="i_n_date fs13 light">DATE</div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <div class="table-cell">
        <a href="#href" class="underline">
          <div class="i_n_title fs16 bold">11111</div>
        </a>
        <div class="i_n_desc fs16 light">1111</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-rel="n" class="i_n_block clearfix" style="display:none;">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="i_n_date fs13 light">DATE</div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <div class="table-cell">
        <a href="#href" class="underline">
          <div class="i_n_title fs16 bold">22222222222222222222222222222222222222222 22222222222</div>
        </a>
        <div class="i_n_desc fs16 light">22222222222222 222222222222 22222222</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="i-n-control">
    <div class="left">ww</div>
    <div class="right">ee</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо, сделал по образу, только в таком стиле:
`elem.next().show();
var le = elem.next().find(".right").height();
elem.next().hide();`
хотя можно было и overflow воспользоваться

Comment: как вариант... удачи..))